# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_createFromLocal'

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to create a Dataframe from list with single column in pyspark but facing error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_createFromLocal'

---> 24 DF_COLS=SparkSession.createDataFrame(src_cols, schema)
     25 DF_COLS.show()
     26

C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    746             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    747         else:
--> 748             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    749         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    750         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_createFromLocal'

```
STDIN = (sqlContext.read
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load("filepath"))

src_cols = STDIN.columns
src_cols = [tuple(map(str, sub.split(','))) for sub in src_cols]
print (src_cols)

schema = StructType([StructField("colnm", StringType(), True)])

DF_COLS=SparkSession.createDataFrame(src_cols, schema)
DF_COLS.show()
```

Comment: it would be helpful to show a small sample of that src_cols and your data looks like

Comment: print (src_cols)-->
[('Secret_Row1',), ('Secret_Row2',), ('PUBLIC_Row3',), ('PUBLIC_Row4',), ('PUBLIC_Row5',), ('Secret_Row6',), ('Secret_Row7',), ('PUBLIC_Row8',), ('Secret_Row9',), ('Secret_Row10',)]

Comment: Right, What I am trying to understand is what is the output of `tuple(map(str, sub.split(','))) for sub in src_cols` given your data. Your comment above containing a sample as `Secret_Row1` which does not have a ',' does not help. The more details you can provide the better.

Comment: Thanks for help @Jaime . It is solve now. I have used sqlContext.createDataFrame instead of SparkSession.createDataFrame and It worked like magic.

Comment: oh wow! I didnt event notice that, on my end we usually do `spark.createDataFrame` but only becuase the spark variable is initialized by jupyter lab. The things we take for granted! :) Glad to hear it all worked out!